# How to deploy JS app that has code splitting, making sure past app versions don't break

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, progressive-web-apps, code-splitting

I have a simple PWA app built with Webpack and React.
It has code splitting setup on dynamic imports (e.g. `React.lazy(() => import('./SomeRoute'))`) so different routes get different JS bundles, e.g.: `main.bundle.js`, `someRoute.bundle.js`

Now imagine the situation: I deploy a new version of the app that doesn't have `SomeRoute` at all or has something completely different in it. The app would try to reach `https://myapp.com/someRoute.bundle.js` and fail as that asset is no longer there. App reload would obviously help, but still, that won't be a pleasant behaviour.

One solution that I see would be to include the content hash into all assets, so it would be `someRoute.1e4f.js` and then **host all those different app versions for some time period**, until all app users have the latest version of the app.

If this is the way to go, then I don't know how to organise it. I currently host my PWA with vercel.com (ex. Zeit), and I never saw if they have the feature to keep assets from past builds available.
Of course I could commit all build artefacts into git, but that would very quickly bloat the repo.

Another solution would be to **pre-fetch all app's routes at initial load** and keep them cached in a service worker. That would obviously help, but it defeats the purpose of code-splitting to reduce the network traffic usage.

Another solution is to **detect 404 on JS chunks and force-reload the app**. That would be a very unpleasant UX for some users.

So how do serious apps handle it? I'm surprised how such essential problem lacks attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this topic and indeed there's nothing to add besides what I've already mentioned in the question. I've explained it more verbosely in this article: http://dimaip.github.io/2020/04/25/deploying-apps-with-code-splitting/